# UITabBarItem images just appear as a grey block

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have created .png icons 20 x 20 and when I set the image property in the nib they just appear grey blocks.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  Here is one of the icons!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard tabbar icons in iOS are rendered solely from the alpha channel. Colors are ignored completely. Instead of colors you can use different alpha values that lead to a different shade of gray (or blue if selected)

Make the background of your icons transparent.

Answer (score 3):

Download these attached images and pass them to your designer and ask him to just create images like these (when you open them in PS you'll know the difference)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in iOS 5, I got around it by setting UIImage Outlet property in the Xib to 'Custom' and then set the label programmtically so : imageOne = [UIImage imageNames@"Dog.png"];

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the file as png interlaced.  In photoshop at least it gives you an option of interlaced or normal.