# How do I create custom tab bar icons?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, icons, uitabbar

I know this question has been asked many times before but their solutions haven't worked for me. I want to create a custom tab bar item icon. My understanding is that you create one version which is a white outline (alpha set to 1) with a transparent background and a filled-in version (also with a transparent background). The unselected image works but when you tap the icon it disappears in the simulator.

simulator unselected version:
[image: unselected bar item]
simulator selected version:
[image: selected]

I haven't been setting the images programmatically, just using the attributes inspector. I even looked at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429844/swift-and-xcode-how-to-create-custom-tab-bar-icons) and replaced my image with the one they suggested and the same thing happened.

Here are my Xcode settings if that helps:
[image: Xcode attributes inspector]

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I left the selected image dropdown blank and now the icon doesn't disappear. My problem isn't resolved because I don't just want a solid blue version of the image I want a blue outline.

[image]